# MS format tag for Opus codec

Tags: audio, directshow, opus

Is there a defined format tag for Opus that should be used with the WAVEFORMATEX structure? See [`WAVEFORMATEX` structure, `wFormatTag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970).

Answer (score 1):

Windows SDK defines `WAVE_FORMAT_OPUS` (0x704F == 'Op') and [`MFAudioFormat_Opus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372553) which is a Media Foundation equivalent for supposed `MEDIASUBTYPE_OPUS`, and is a standard FourCC based mapping from `WAVE_FORMAT_OPUS`.

That is, those are suggested for use identifiers.

However though, Microsoft's own implementation of Opus decoder is not available to public and reserved for use in Microsoft's products (presumably Edge browser), so there is no adopted practice and even documentation more on these identifiers, and everyone on his own how to use them (or use something else instead).

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a formal format tag for Opus, I will use [WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757714.aspx) instead, using MEDIASUBTYPE_OPUS for the SubFormat parameter.

```
#define WAVE_FORMAT_OPUS      mmioFOURCC('O','P','U','S')
DEFINE_GUID(MEDIASUBTYPE_OPUS,
  WAVE_FORMAT_OPUS, 0x0000, 0x0010, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x38, 0x9b, 0x71);
```

> WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE allows you to avoid having to register a new format tag with Microsoft.

See MMReg.h in Windows SDK